# Do subhomomorphisms / subfunctors have a standard name, and where can I learn more?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory, terminology, order-theory

*Sorry for all the mistakes in the original! I think they're mostly fixed now.*

*Thank you for your patience.*

**Part 1.** If $A$ and $B$ are models in $\mathrm{Pos}$ of an algebraic signature $\sigma$, the usual definition of *homomorphism* is a function $f : A \rightarrow B$ that furthermore satisfies the following requirements.

$\quad$ Condition I. $a \leq_A a' \rightarrow f(a) \leq_B f(a')$

$\quad$ Condition IIa. $f(O_A(a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1}))=O_B(f(a_0),\cdots,f(a_{n-1}))$

Of course, IIa should be taken to hold for all natural $n$ and all function symbols $O$ of $\sigma$ having airity $n$.

Okay, so those are the usual definitions; however, there is a very natural generalization whereby IIa is weakened to the following.

$\quad$ Condition IIb. $f(O_A(a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1})) \leq_B O_B(f(a_0),\cdots,f(a_{n-1}))$

Lets call functions satisfying both I and IIb *subhomomorphisms.*

*Example.* Let $A$ denote the ordered monoid (written additively), with underlying set $\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ and the usual notion of addition, but the **reverse** ordering.

Then the unique function $f : A \rightarrow A$ with defining property $f(a)=a^2$ is a subhomomorphism, since we can argue as follows.

$$f(a+b) = a^2+b^2 + 2ab \geq a^2+b^2 = f(a)+f(b)$$

**Question 1.** Do subhomomorphisms have a standard name, and where can I learn more about them?

Note that, as an immediate consequence of the definitions, the identity function is always a subhomomorphism, and the composition of two subhomomorphisms is also a subhomomorphism. Thus, classes of ordered algebraic structures over a common signature form naturally into categories whose arrows are precisely the subhomomorphisms.

*Actually*, they form naturally into [2-posets](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-poset), where by "2-poset" I just mean a category enriched in $\mathrm{Pos}$, which somewhat motivates my next question.

**Part 2.** Given a pair of 2-posets $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, there is an obvious definition of "subfunctor" $F : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D},$ obtained by weakening the usual demands on $F.$ In particular, we're merely assuming the following.

1. $F(\mathrm{id}_X) \leq \mathrm{id}_{F(X)},$ for all objects $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$.
2. $F(g \circ f) \leq F(g) \circ F(f),$ for all serial pairs of arrows $f,g$ of $\mathcal{C}$.

We must also add the stipulation that $F$ preserves order when restricted to any given homset; otherwise, the composition of a pair of compatible subfunctors needn't be a subfunctor.

**Question 2.** Do subfunctors between 2-posets have a standard name, and where can I learn more about them?

*Motivation.* I think that, if $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are 2-posets whose objects are ordered algebraic structures and whose arrows are subhomomorphisms, then it would be most natural to view $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D})$ as consisting of all subfunctors. I have yet to find any evidence for this hunch.

Note that many new phenomena emerge in the passage from functors to subfunctors. In particular, while the value assigned by a functor to the hypotenuse of a commutative triangle is determined by the values it assigns to the other arrows, this is not true for an arbitrary subfunctor.

Comment: Sublinear maps have been studied and appear for example in the Hahn-Banach Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublinear_function).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, thanks.

Comment: For your second question, this seems to coincide with the notion of *colax functors* between 2-categories (regarding each hom-poset as category).

Comment: @Berci, I'm new to these terms; is that the same as an "oplax functor"?

Comment: Yes, yes. It is called lax functor for the reverse direction ($F(g\circ f)\leftarrow F(g)\circ F(f)$..)